# How to calculate transaction fee using ethers.js

Tags: transactions, gas, ethers.js, gas-estimate, fees

I am trying to calculate the transaction fee of a tx before prompting MetaMask using ethers.js. So for I have:

```
const gasPrice = ethers.utils.formatUnits(await ethers.getDefaultProvider().getGasPrice(), 'ether');
const gasUnits = parseInt(
    (
        await new Contract(
            address,
            abi,
            ethers.getDefaultProvider()
        ).estimateGas.functionName(params)
    )._hex,
    16
);
const transactionFee = parseFloat(gasPrice) * gasUnits;
```

This looks like it should work but `transactionFee` is off by a factor of around 10. I don't know if this is just a coincidence or I parsed one of the numbers incorrectly. Please help.

Comment: How do you see your transaction fee is off?

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the code as the following to avoid all unnecessary conversions that can induce errors:

```js
    const gasPrice = await ethers.getDefaultProvider().getGasPrice();
    const gasUnits =
        await new Contract(
            address,
            abi,
            ethers.getDefaultProvider()
        ).estimateGas.functionName(params);

    const transactionFee = gasPrice.mul(gasUnits);
    console.log("transactionFee in wei: " + transactionFee.toString());
    console.log("transactionFee in ether: " + ethers.utils.formatUnits(transactionFee, "ether"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be rounding? When working with Wei and BigNumbers, I've found that native parseFloat and parseInt usually do some kind of unwanted rounding. Using web3 specific unit libraries has been extremely helpful, here's a good one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-units, written by the CEO of PrimitiveFi.

Comment: Actually, I think it was a coincidence that it seemed to work. A few hours later, transactionFee is now off by a factor of 20.